# BJT or MOS negative feedback analysis

Tags: mosfet, bjt, negative-feedback

I am looking for a resource that includes analysis of feedback circuits. I have found something on *sedra smith microelectronic circuits* but not enough for me. Could you suggest me some resource ? It may be article, book, internet resource or anything else.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because reference requests are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange platform. The topic of "negative feedback" is rather broad and vague as well. Instead, please open a question that directly addresses a technical gap in *Sedra+Smith*'s treatment of negative feedback, with appropriate detail/context.

Comment: @nanofarad I'd like to learn how to BJT and MOS with feedback analysis. For this, I am looking a resource.

Comment: Consider MIT opencourseware then -- the only resource I can personally vouch for is my undergrad lectures, and MIT OCW purports itself to be an approximate equivalent.

Comment: lookup for Razavi Electronics lectures on youtube. He has a good treatment of negative feedback for transistor circuits.